# Enable disable bluetooth with nfc on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, nfc

I have a windows phone in my posession and now I want to automaticly enable/disable bluetooth on my phone using nfc tags.

Now I found already that you can summon the nfc settings page where you then manually change the bluetooth settings. That's nice but this requires me to tap 2 times before it's enabled.

I searched for some code to help me but I only found how to get the bluetooth form:
[MSDN link: How to use the connection settings task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394011%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Now is it possible that I can enable or disable these settings via a small application.
And if it's possible can I pass parameters also so that I can send a parameter -enable 1 to enable it and -enable 0 to disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot disable nor enable Bluetooth from your application. As a matter of fact, the security system prevents you from changing *any* system settings at all.

That is why you have launchers that will take user to the desired settings page and then the user can change it there manually.

Comment: I already thought something like this was the reason. In a security view it's normal behaviour. Thx